# WIndows server 2012 will not allow mirroring drives/partitions

Tags: partitioning, raid, windows-server-2012, mirroring

I have a dell c1100 server and it gave me a hard time installing windows server 2012.

Now installed, I want to setup mirroring inside windows (raid 1 effectively).

In disk management, I right click the partition and add mirror is grayed out. What can I do. I have two of the same exact drives in the server. Both say Layout simple, type basic. The second disk is not formatted yet.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to mirror the system partition where windows is installed? Windows can't use mirroring on the system partition (by default, you can force it to do it by manually editing the registry).

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you want software raid? These systems usually come with a hardware raid controller.

Comment: This c1100 has an intel built in raid which is basically software raid. I can't get it to detect the 3tb drives...only shows 750gb. Windows alone can see the 3tb drives, but is very odd with them. I get one 2tb partition and another of 750gb. It won't let me make one big partition and won't let me use the 750gb unallocated space...so I think i'm stuck with only 2tb. But that's better than 750gb. Now if I can only have windows raid it for me (mirror) to a Raid 1. Then I'll be fine. Alternatively if I can find out how to get the intel raid to give me the full capacity, I'll go with that method.

Answer (score 1):

i know its an old forum.
Mirror is grayed out because the volumes are using GPT and not MBR system.
But then MBR doesnt work on anything bigger than 2TB.

Personally for a basic file server, Software Raid will do ok for you using Windows server diskmgmt.msc. If you want more space in this case, you should have used 3 x 2TB disks and use Raid-5 using Diskmgmt.msc in the server.
that would have brought your space to 4TB in total {(2+2+2)-2}.

I KNOW if you go with 2TB drives, Use DiskPart to ensure you convert your system (primary) hard disk to MBR before installing windows, it will 100000% work fine for you.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have one myself but going through the web, found these two tutorials which are pretty good in my opinion. Have a look. I might add that these are for Windows server 2008 but may also work on server 2012.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23476

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_and_Managing_Windows_Server_2008_Mirrored_%28RAID_1%29_Volumes

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Windows Server 2012, however the old advice used to be that the disks had to be dynamic disks which is a process that can break dual boot:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738132%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

In fact even more evidence suggest the process is the same. In device manager you need to convert the drives to dynamic and then the right click option will allow you to mirror them.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/1b0ef255-32b2-4cc9-bc98-376ba4c0c7f0/how-to-mirror-boot-drive-in-windows-2012-rc